# Azure devops not showing the testsuite name under a testsuite in the report(xml) section of the pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, postman

I am generating xml reports via postman in the azure devops pipeline. My Postman collection structure is below:

Collection name->Folder name->Requests(Containing test cases)

When the xml report gets generated then it looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="Suite1" tests="2" time="1.317">
  <testsuite name="Folder1 / Request1" id="abc" timestamp="time/date" tests="1" failures="1" errors="0" time="0.658">
    <testcase name="Verify that the success status code is 200" time="0.179" classname="ABC">
      <failure type="AssertionFailure" message="expected response to have status code 200 but got 401">
```

I expect from Azure devops to show the generated & categorize xml report as:
Suite1->Folder1->Test cases inside Request1

but it actually shows like below:
Suite1->Test cases inside Request1

I expect all the test cases to be inside "Folder1" instead of Suite1. SomeHow it is skipping the "Folder1" inside "Suite1". Let me know if needed more explanation.

Comment: Could your share the url of request1? What api is request1 calling?

Comment: Cannot share the request url keeping the security in mind. But its a get request containing the test cases inside it.

Comment: Could check the test and test plan api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), and kindly advise which specific api your request is calling?

Comment: You can omit the sensitive information like this example https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/testplan/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1